# To whom should the letter of motivation be addressed?

Tags: phd

I am applying for a Phd position advertised by the university. Should I address my letter of motivation to the potential supervisor? Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, you address your letter to the contact mentioned in the advertisement.

As last resort, you can always used an undetermined Sir, Madam.

Answer (score 0):

> To whom it may concern

Really, don't loose any time on the header of the letter, keep your focus on the rest, that is the part they are actually going to read.